# Pandas upsampling does not include the 23 hours of last day in year

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory, pandas-resample

I have a time series dataframe with dates|weather information that looks like this:

[image]

```
2017-01-01 5
2017-01-02 10
.
.
2017-12-31 6
```

I am trying to upsample it to hourly data using the following:
`weather.resample('H').pad()`

I expected to see 8760 entries for 24 intervals * 365 days. However, it only returns 8737 with the last 23 intervals missing for 31st of december. Is there something special I need to do to get 24 intervals for the last day?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi There, welcome to SO, great first question. You're very close to having an [mcve] I would suggest providing some code to recreate your data frame or paste it in as text.

Comment: Prepare a valid value for 2018-01-01 at the end of the data and call resample. If you delete the data of 2018-01-01 after resample, there will be 8760 data.

Comment: @kunif you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Pandas normalizes `2017-12-31` to `2017-12-31 00:00` and then creates a range that ends in that last datetime... I would include a last row before resampling with

```
df.loc['2018-01-01'] = 0
```

---

Edit:
You can get the result you want with `numpy.repeat`

Take this df

```
np.random.seed(1)
weather = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31'),
    data={'WEATHER_MAX': np.random.random(365)*15})

            WEATHER_MAX
2017-01-01     6.255330
2017-01-02    10.804867
2017-01-03     0.001716
2017-01-04     4.534989
2017-01-05     2.201338
...                 ...
2017-12-27     4.503725
2017-12-28     2.145087
2017-12-29    13.519627
2017-12-30     8.123391
2017-12-31    14.621106

[365 rows x 1 columns]
```

By repeating on `axis=1` you can then transform the default `range(24)` column names to hourly timediffs

```
# repeat, then stack
hourly = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(weather.values, 24, axis=1),
    index=weather.index).stack()

# combine date and hour
hourly.index = (
    hourly.index.get_level_values(0) +
    pd.to_timedelta(hourly.index.get_level_values(1), unit='h')
)
hourly = hourly.rename('WEATHER_MAX').to_frame()
```

Output

```
                     WEATHER_MAX
2017-01-01 00:00:00     6.255330
2017-01-01 01:00:00     6.255330
2017-01-01 02:00:00     6.255330
2017-01-01 03:00:00     6.255330
2017-01-01 04:00:00     6.255330
...                          ...
2017-12-31 19:00:00    14.621106
2017-12-31 20:00:00    14.621106
2017-12-31 21:00:00    14.621106
2017-12-31 22:00:00    14.621106
2017-12-31 23:00:00    14.621106

[8760 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the issue. I was able to fix it with the suggestions above although I was expecting an in-built functionality within resample to get what I needed.

Comment: I understand, if you think about it, this should be the expected behavior, so when you have datetime instead of just date (e.g. `2017-12-31 15:45`), the resample will not go past that last datetime

Comment: May I ask what you will be using this resample for? perhaps you can avoid resampling and take advantage of numpy's broadcasting

Comment: Trying to preprocess and combine energy consumption data that is hourly with weather data given in daily format. I am trying to resample the weather data to hourly so I have hourly data across the board. I did not encounter the issue with consumption data since it was already hourly.

Answer (score 0):

What to do and the reason are the same as @RichieV's answer.
However, the value to be used is not 0 or a meaningless value, it is necessary to use valid data actually measured on 2018-01-01.

This is because using a meaningless value reduces the effectiveness of the resampled 2017-12-31 data and the results derived using that data.

1. Prepare a valid value for 2018-01-01 at the end of the data.
2. Call resample.
3. Delete the data of 2018-01-01 after resample.
4. You will get 8670 data for 2017.

---

**Look at @RichieV's modified answer:**

I was misunderstanding the question.
My answer was to complement resample with interpolate etc.
[resampleを用いた外挿 (データ補間) を行いたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/65666/26370)

If the same value as 00:00 on the day is all right, it would be a different way of thinking.